# Laravel: How to redirect a request to controller function and use View::make at the same time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

```
**Route**
Route::get('admin', function()
{
     return View::make('theme-admin.main');
});

**Controller**
class Admin_Controller extends Base_Controller {

public function action_index()
{
    echo __FUNCTION__;
}
```

If I forward request to controller, then I have to define `View::make` in every function in controller. If I don't forward it, `action function` doesn't work.

Should I just forward requests to controller and use `View::make` inside action functions or there are better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually isn't necessary to define `View::make` in every function of your controllers.

You can, for example, execute an action and then redirect to another action, that could `View::make`.

Let's say you want to create an user and then show its profile, in a RESTful way. You could do:

```
# POST /users
public function user_create()
{
    $user = User::create(...);

    // after you have created the user, redirect to its profile
    return Redirect::to_action('users@show', array($user->id));

    // you don't render a view here!
}


# GET /users/1
public function get_show($id)
{
    return View::make('user.show');
}
```

Comment: Instead of Redirect::to_action it should be Redirect::action, at least in laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the controller function like this

```
$app = app();
$controller = $app->make('App\Http\Controllers\EntryController');
return $controller->callAction('getEntry', $parameters = array());
```

or you can simply dispatch the request to another controller url

```
$request = \Request::create(route("entryPiont"), 'POST', array()));
return \Route::dispatch($request);
```